# Deepdiff - Iterable_compare_func not working properly

Tags: python, iterable, deep-diff

I am facing recently an issue regarding the compare function 'iterable_compare_func'. Basically deepdiff return a wrong diff.

I test with exactly the same two lists described in the documentation and the result is not the same.

```
from deepdiff import DeepDiff
from deepdiff.helper import CannotCompare

t1 = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'value': [1]
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'value': [7, 8, 1]
    },
    {
        'id': 3,
        'value': [7, 8],
    },
]

t2 = [
    {
        'id': 2,
        'value': [7, 8]
    },
    {
        'id': 3,
        'value': [7, 8, 1],
    },
    {
        'id': 1,
        'value': [1]
    },
]
```

```
>>> DeepDiff(t1, t2)

{'values_changed': {"root[0]['id']": {'new_value': 2, 'old_value': 1}, "root[0]['value'][0]": {'new_value': 7, 'old_value': 1}, "root[1]['id']": {'new_value': 3, 'old_value': 2}, "root[2]['id']": {'new_value': 1, 'old_value': 3}, "root[2]['value'][0]": {'new_value': 1, 'old_value': 7}}, 'iterable_item_added': {"root[0]['value'][1]": 8}, 'iterable_item_removed': {"root[2]['value'][1]": 8}}
```

*iterable_compare_func*.

```
def compare_func(x, y, level=None):
    try:
        return x['id'] == y['id']
    except Exception:
        raise CannotCompare() from None
```

now by setting the function. the result is wrong as below.

```
>>> DeepDiff(t1, t2, iterable_compare_func=compare_func)
{}
>>> DeepDiff(t1, t2, iterable_compare_func=compare_func, verbose_level=2)
{'iterable_item_moved': {'root[0]': {'new_path': 'root[2]', 'value': {'id': 1, 'value': [1]}}, 'root[1]': {'new_path': 'root[0]', 'value': {'id': 2, 'value': [7, 8]}}, 'root[2]': {'new_path': 'root[1]', 'value': {'id': 3, 'value': [7, 8, 1]}}}}
```

The issue is encountered with deepdiff v6.3.1 and the same issue is validated within 2 different environments.
If anyone had the same issue or can reproduce to confirm.

Thank you.

Expected is as what the documentation describes : iterable_compare_func helps to define what elements to compare to others and here we define that the elements with same IDs should be compared with each other.

https://zepworks.com/deepdiff/6.3.1/custom.html